# Запись в MSAccess, c#

Tags: c#, ado.net, ms-access

Выдаёт такую ошибку при попытки записать в бд.
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO."

```
  OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\комп\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Access\myDB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False");
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection= myConnection;
        myConnection.Open();
        if (myConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        { 
            string sql_command = "";
            stpWatch.Start();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sql_command += "INSERT INTO person ([name], [sex]) VALES('pap', 'fdd')";
            cmd.CommandText = sql_command;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery());
                stpWatch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(stpWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
```

Comment: `VALES` -> `VALUES`  "Потолковать о Ювенале, В конце письма поставить *vale* ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы сделали ошибку при написании ключевого слова VAL**U**ES, корректная команда будет:   `INSERT INTO person ([name], [sex]) VALUES('pap', 'fdd')`